# Shifting elements in an array by a non integer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, interpolation

I wanted to know if there is a way to somehow shift an array by a non integer value in python. Let's say I have a matrix `T[i,j]` and I want to interpolate the value of `T[1.3,4.5]` by using `T[1,4], T[1,5], T[2,4] and T[2,5]`. Is there a simple and fast way to do that?
I have been stuck trying to use `scipy.ndimage.shift()` for the past few hours but I couldn't understand how to make it work.

Comment: You're looking for "interpolation", not "shifting".  Scipy has an `interpolate` module, but I'm not familiar enough with its usage to make any specific recommendation on how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** It seems this can be accomplished with scipy.interpolation.interp2d, though interp2d serves a more general purpose and thus may be slower in this case.

You'd want to do something like `iT = interp2d(range(T.shape[0]),range(T.shape[1]),T.T)`. Please note that, in the `T.T` at the end, the `.T` stands for transpose, and has nothing to do with the fact that the array is called `T`. `iT` can be accessed as a function, for instance, `print(iT(1.1,2.3))`.

It will return arrays, as opposed to single values, which indicates that one can pass arrays as arguments too (i.e. compute the value of the interpolation at several points "at once".

---

I am not aware of any standard way to do this. I'd accomplish it by simply wrapping the array in an instance of some kind of "interpolated array" class. For simplicity, let's start by assuming T is a 1D array:

```
class InterpolatedArray:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        i0 = int(i)
        i1 = i0+1
        f = i-i0
        return self.array[i0]*(1-f)+self.array[i1]*f
```

As you can see, it overloads the subscripting routine, so that when you attempt to access (for instance) `array[1.1]`, this returns `0.9*array[1]+0.1*array[2]`. You'd have to explicitly build this object from your previous array:

```
iT = InterpolatedArray(T)
print(iT[1.1])
```

As for the two-dimensional case, it works the same, just with a little bit more work on the indexing:

```
class InterpolatedMatrix:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array
    def __getitem__(self, i, j):
        i0 = int(i)
        i1 = i0+1
        fi = i-i0

        j0 = int(j)
        j1 = j0+1
        fj = j-j0

        return self.array[i0,j0]*(1-fi)*(1-fj)\
               +self.array[i1,j0]*fi*(1-fj)\
               +self.array[i0,j1]*(1-fi)*fj\
               +self.array[i1,j1]*fi*fj\
```

You can probably rewrite some of that code to optimize the amount of operations that are performed.

Note, also, that if for some reason you want to access every index in the image with some small fixed offset (i.e. T[i+0.3,j+0.5] for i,j in T.shape), then it would be better to do this with vectorization, using numpy (something similar may also be possible with scipy).